# Mail Function in PHP is returning False Without Error Without Sending . Why it is so

Tags: php, email

Pls Guide Simple code here is not sending mail.
The following Code is returning False and not returning any error message.
I have already done the needful setting in PHP.ini and sendmail.ini.

```
<?php  

    $to = "husainsalik@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Test subject";
    $body = "Test Body";
    $header = 'husainsalik@gmail.com';
    

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);

    if($send)
    {
        echo "Mail Sent √";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Mail Failed"; 
    }

?>
```

The above code is returning Mail Failed.

Comment: <?php  
    $to = "husainsalik@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Test subject";
    $body = "Test Body";
    $header = 'husainsalik@gmail.com';
    
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
    if($send)
    {
     echo "Mail Sent √";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "Mail Failed"; 
    }
?>

Comment: There are a lot of potential problems. Email is actually quite a complex business. See here: [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: This question has been asked many times on Stack Overflow. The short answer is: Don't use GMail to test a mail server. GMail doesn't know your mail server, and will block any emails from it. Start by looking into SPF and DKIM. See also: https://support.google.com/a/topic/9061731